# Select solo agarra ultimo valor

Tags: laravel, select, vistas

Tengo, este `select`.

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control" >
    @foreach($sede as $user)
        @if($user->idSede != $coordinadorAdm->Sede)
          <option value="{{$user->idSede}}">{{$user->nombre}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

EL problema esta en que si necesito enviar el `$user->idSede` seleccionado, este no lo toma, si no que siempre tiene el ultimo valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desea que cargue el select con un valor seleccionado ? ¿ Es una vista editar ? ¿Le envía un objeto a la vista con los datos para tomar en cuenta para la selección?

Comment: Si, deseo que cargué el valor que estoy seleccionando del select, es una vista de edición, Si envío el objeto, el problema que estoy teniendo es que aunque tengo seleccionada una determinada Sede, cuando envío los parámetros el idSede siempre me agarra la última Sede, yo la que yo tengo seleccionada en el option.

Answer (score 0):

Podría emplear `old()` *(no sé que name tiene su select , es el valor que debe ir en el old)* de la siguiente forma , haciendo una validación extra con un `if else` pero con el formato de [Un operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) para saber a cual `option` se le da el atributo `selected`

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control" >
  @foreach($sede as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->idSede }}" 
     {{ ($user->idSede == $coordinadorAdm->Sede || old('sede') == $coordinadorAdm->Sede )? 'selected' : '' }}>
{{ $user->nombre }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Ya lo intente, y nada, sigue enviando como parámetro el ultimo id de esa tabla.

Comment: Adjunto a la pregunta la imagen, explico que estoy haciendo. Desde el controlador, selecciono todas las sedes y las paso a la vista, una vez en la vista, necesita enviar dos parametros al controlador, el primero de la primera sede, esta perfecto, pero el segundo parametro el cual es el idSede de otra Sede que estoy seleccionando como opcion, no me esta agarrando si no el último id.

Comment: Comprendí la primera parte envía todas las sedes y llena los dos selects , luego selecciona la primera sede, en la imagen sería el select que está deshabilitado,  _(pero el segundo parámetro el cual es el idSede de otra Sede que estoy seleccionando como opción)_  ¿Qué otra sede? ¿También la envía desde el controlador ? o selecciona en la modal y luego pasa a otra vista esos datos ? ¿Una vez seleccionado 
 Cómo pasa estos dos  datos al controlador ? ¿Desde el controlador no puede acceder? _(recuerde que le hace falta el atributo name al select)_

Comment: La envío desde el controlador, mi problema esta en que el segundo select que esta en la imagen, si yo cambio de una sede a otra en ese select, el id debería de cambiar  porque estoy cambiado la Sede, más sin embargo siempre se muestra el id de la ultima sede, Si vemos en la imagen tengo seleccionada la Sede 4 cuyo Id es 4, pero cuando cuando envío los parámetros esta enviándose es el id de la Sede 5, que se observa en la parte inferior de la imagen.